# How can I view in Google Analytics the number of sessions where one of a few pages were viewed?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, session, page-views

I want to count the number of sessions in Google Analytics so that:

1. **at least one** of Page A, Page B or Page C were viewed
2. **avoid counting twice** sessions where there was more than 1 view of these pages (e.g. where Page A and Page C were both viewed).

Simply summing up unique pageviews doesn't do the trick, since I count twice sessions that included Page A and Page C.

Is there a way to configure a report to do so? Other way?

Answer (score 1):

Create a segment with conditions per session:

Filter 1:

Page matches regex "Page A" AND Page does not match regex "Page B" AND Page does not match regex "Page C"

Filter 2:

Page does not match regex "Page A" AND Page matches regex "Page B" AND Page does not match regex "Page C"

Filter 3:

Page does not match regex "Page A" AND Page does not match regex "Page B" AND Page matches regex "Page C"

[image: segment]